# sum of poisson and gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ is there any name for the distribution of $Z = Y + X $ ?

Comment: There is no special term for it in [this article](http://sankhya.isical.ac.in/search/74a1/13171_2012_5_PrintPDF.pdf).

Comment: Very nice link! Thanks! ;-)